# linkout failing with conflicting JSESSIONID

Tags: jsessionid

I have an issue with the linkout of my application (say App2) on another application (say App1).

Both are web applications and so both are creating there own JSESSION IDs. The linkout opens in a pop up and single sign on works (siteminder passing the sm user cookie), but as soon as I perform any transaction on the linked application I am thrown out stating the session is either timed out or invalid.

I looked at the cookies present on the browser and found that both the JSESSION IDs are present. The only difference is in the domain scope of both the JSESSION IDs.  App1 application has domain scope of say abc.com whereas App2 has app2.abc.com

I tried changing the name of the JSESSION ID cookie of App2 but the application did not work with the renamed JSESSION cookie.

Any suggestion on how can I fix this ?

Note : The environment for App2 is was5

Regards
AVN

Answer (score 0):

You should use different cookie name in config.xml. Change any one of the app to use different cookie name other than JSESSIONID. Something like following.

```
War:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90">
    <session-descriptor>
        <cookie-name>APP1SESSIONID </cookie-name>
    </session-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>

Ear:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90">
    <session-descriptor>
        <cookie-name>APP1SESSIONID </cookie-name>
    </session-descriptor>
</weblogic-application>
```

Now you will have both the cookies and it will not overwrite one another.